# Get frontend translation phrases

Tags: magento2, localisation, translation-dictionaries

I'm trying to collect all phrases for a customer. When I ran `bin/magento i18:collect-phrases` I get all the phrases in the admin section and I don't want that because it is way to much.

I thought of collecting all phrases from /code/desing/frontend, the problem with this is that it will not collect core templates that are not overridden by my custom theme.

Is there a way / tool to collect only frontend phrases?

*note: I know inline translations exists but I want a csv file with all labels / phrases to be translated.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% this will work but if your template is based on luma theme for example in addition to design folder you mention in question try scanning the /vendor/magento luma theme folder? If theme based on blank try vendor/magento blank theme folder.

`/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank`

`/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma`

Comment: Yes, I agree. I don't think I will have everything (3rd party modules, checkout, ...) but so be it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Just found out there are no translation labels in  the Magento Blank theme.